# Proving equation (with Hilbert symbol)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field with non-zero elements $a,b,c \in K$ and let $(. , .)$ be the Hilbert symbol.

Let $(a,-c)=(-1,ac)$ and $(b,-c)=(-1,bc)$.

How to show that $(-ab,-c)=(-1,-abc)$ ?

Comment: I've computed:
$(-ab,-c)=(-c,a)(-c,-b)=(-1,ac)(-c,-b)=(-1,ac)(-c,b)(-c,-1)=(-1,ac)(-1,bc)(-1,-c)=(-1,-acbcc)$.

But where is a mistake?

Comment: There is no mistake. Recall the definition of Hilbert symbol: $(-1, c^2) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! It's clear now :-)